# Java array of primitive data types

Tags: java, arrays, types, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Why next code works like it uses reference types rather than primitive types?

```
int[] a = new int[5];
int[] b = a;
a[0] = 1;
b[0] = 2;
a[1] = 1;
b[1] = 3;
System.out.println(a[0]);
System.out.println(b[0]);
System.out.println(a[1]);
System.out.println(b[1]);
```

And the output is:
2
2
3
3
rather than
1
2
1
3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The contents of the int array may not be references, but the int[] variables **are**.  By setting `b = a` you're copying the reference and the two arrays are pointing to the same chunk of memory.

Answer (score 2):

I describe what you are doing here:

1. creating an array of integers `int[] a = new int[5];`
2. creating a reference to created array `int[] b = a;`
3. adding integer to array "a", position 0
4. overwriting previously added integer, because b[0] is pointing to the same location as a[0]
5. adding integer to array "a", position 1
6. overwriting previously added integer again, because b[1] is pointing to the same location as a[1]

Answer (score 0):

you are not creating a new instance by `int[] b = a`

if you need new instance (and your expected result) add `clone()`: `int[] b = a.clone()`

good luck

Comment: So array is an object with just reference?

Comment: @IgorDiy yes, an array is an object, most operations on arrays do not copy them (it would be terribly expensive to call a method with an array as argument if it had to be copied!)

Comment: @IgorDiy, it is an object, it does even inherit object for instance new int[2].getClass().getSuperClass() return Object.class. As a bonus it does have all the methods an object has.

Answer (score 0):

Both `a` and `b` points to (*is*) the same array. Changing a value in either `a` or `b` will change the same value for the other.